# Does superconducting magnet prevents energy loss when hadron is being accelerated?

Tags: energy, superconductivity, large-hadron-collider

I read up on how synchrotron works and  electron will heats up by emitting photon when it is steering(accelerating) around a bend, so more bends more heat loss. By heat I mean energy not necessarily infrared light, and I suppose LHC must have ways to prevent such heat loss right? The superconducting magnet is cooled so that electric current can flow easily without burning up the magnet which I suspect would work as well with powerful permanent magnet, so I like to know how the superconducting magnet prevents accelerating hadron from losing energy?

Comment: Nope. No way to prevent the energy loss except keep adding more energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of superconducting magnets does not decrease the energy loss of the beam. If anything, it increases it, because superconducting magnets can have a higher field, hence sharper bending.

But the superconducting magnets do save an immense amount of energy that would otherwise by lost to resistance of the excitation currents in the magnets. Copper wire would turn a lot of energy into I*R heat.